# Accessing to the argument of a declared function

Tags: c, function, callback, typedef

I have the following function declaration:

```
typedef void (cback) (scan_results *scan_result, uint8_t *adv_data);
```

I declare the function as follows:

```
cback my_cback;
```

I give `my_cback` to a function as an input. Then, I want to access the arguments of `my_cback`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure these two lines will compile?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it will compile

Comment: Surprisingly it is compiled, while I would not expect variables of a function type to be legal, as I really don't see any valid usage of these. You want a function pointer instead, that will point to a specific implementation of `cback`. https://ideone.com/vAddee

Comment: @EugeneSh., expressions of function type decay to function pointers, very much like expressions of array type decay to pointers.  That is in fact why you can pass a function name as an argument corresponding to a function pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What would be a usage of  OP's `my_cback` variable? It can't be assigned.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: These are not expressions of function types. `cback` is a function type, not an expression, and `my_cback` is an identifier (which will not be an expression until used as such).

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's not a variable.  It's a declaration of a function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh. Ok, didn't see it this way. How would you provide a definition of it?

Comment: @EugeneSh: Suppose I declared `cback` to be a pointer to a function, for later use in declaring a parameter that is such a pointer. In the meantime, when I define `my_cback`, I want to ensure it conforms to the intended function type. If `cback` were a pointer, I do not see a way to do that. But, given that it is a type, I can first declare `cback my_cback;` and then define the function with `void my_cback(scan_results *, uint8_t *) {…}`, and the compiler will give me an error if it does not match the `cback` type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, makes sense now.

Comment: @EugeneSh. one would need to write a standard definition of `my_cback`.  You cannot use the typedef alias for that, though of course you need to provide a definition that is compatible with it.

Comment: @AlperenGörmez: In what code do you “want to access the arguments of `my_cback`”? In the code of `my_cback`, you would simply access them by the parameter names, as in any other function. In any other code, the parameters are not in scope.

Comment: Function arguments are local variables, so you can only access them from within that function. The `typedef` doesn't change that.

Comment: @Barmar Re: "Function arguments are local variables".   I'd call these function _parameters_ (C11 3.16) and agree they are local.  The function _arguments_ (C11 3.3) are of course accessible by the calling function.

Comment: @chux I can never remember the distinction between parameters and arguments. In context, it's almost always clear which was intended.

Comment: @Barmar I found [Function arguments are local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730141/accessing-to-the-argument-of-a-declared-function?noredirect=1#comment94314769_53730141) unclear as  with `foo(a,b)`, `a,b` are the function _arguments_ and a not local to the function.  With `foo(int c, inr d)`, `c,d` as function _parameters_ are  local to the function.  Certainly you understand your comment goal - I saw it less clear and possibly mis-understood, hence the clarification attempt.

Comment: @Barmar: Parameter **identifiers** are only visible within their respective functions. The **objects** they name are not only accessible within their respective functions. Each such object exists during execution of the function call and may be accessed by other functions (which will not have a name for such an object but may be able to access it by other means). “Variables” is a crude term; thinking of identifiers and objects is better for understanding C semantics.

Answer (score 3):

With my VC2008 the following compiles and runs:

```
typedef void (cback) (int *scan_result, int *adv_data);

void f(int *scan_result, int *adv_data)
{
    *adv_data= *scan_result;
}
void ftest(cback *g, int k)
{
    int l;
    g(&k, &l);           // call the function passed as argument
    printf("%d\n",l);
}
void test(void)
{
    int i=3, j;
    cback *my_cback= f;   // assign f to a function pointer variable
    my_cback(&i,&j);      // call  the function pointer directly
    printf("%d\n",j);
    ftest(my_cback, 4);   // pass the function pointer
}
```

Output:

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

> I give `my_cback` to a function as an input.
>   Then, I want to access the arguments of my_cback. How can I achieve this?

Pass to the function, (`foobar()` below), not only `my_cback`, but arguments to pass to `my_cback()` too.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char *scan_results;
typedef void (cback) (scan_results *scan_result, uint8_t *adv_data);

// Declare function
cback my_cback;

// Define function
void my_cback(scan_results *scan_result, uint8_t *adv_data) {
  *scan_result = "Hello";
  *adv_data = 42;
}

void foobar(cback foo, scan_results *scan_result, uint8_t *adv_data) {
  (foo)(scan_result, adv_data);
  // access the arguments
  printf("Inside foobar(): scan_result = %s, adv_data = %d\n", *scan_result, 
      *adv_data); 
}

int main() {
  scan_results sr;
  uint8_t data;
  // I give my_cback to a function as an input.
  foobar(my_cback, &sr, &data);
  // access the arguments
  printf("Inside main():   scan_result = %s, adv_data = %d\n", sr, data);
}
```

Output

```
Inside foobar(): scan_result = Hello, adv_data = 42
Inside main():   scan_result = Hello, adv_data = 42
```